# Dependencies not picked up after composer update/install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am using the following image in my deploy script

```
image: php:7-fpm
```

and then do some typical stuff to install my composer dependencies:

```
script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip python-dev git
            - apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mysql-client
            - docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
            - apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common gnupg
            - ./install-composer.sh
            - composer install
```

Issue is that while I see in the console the packages being installed, when I login to the server and go to the vendor dir then the new package (aws-sdk-php) is not in there.

`Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (dev-master 86d1892): 100%`

What goes wrong here?

**Update** 
This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Can u give us your composer json file?

Comment: @Praem Updated my question.

Comment: As far as I know you could use "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel" when working with Laravel.
More info here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel
Meanwhile, still looking at what could be wrong on your composer

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
Also as you say something else must be the root of the issue

Comment: Which user is the deployment running under? Are you sure you're in the correct directory?

Answer (score 2):

Hey dont know much about the `aws` thing but you are trying to load the `php` package for the `aws`in `laravel`. Though `laravel` is a framework for `php` but the `aws` package gives special package for `laravel`. This is the package `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "dev-master"` you stated in your `composer.json`.

Instead include this `"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"` package into your `composer.json`. This is specially crafted for `laravel`. After including run `composer update` and see if the package gets included in the `vendor` directory or not.

Link of respected package at [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel).

Link of respected package at [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel).

Hope it helps.